# Is there a general way to find the fixed points of a quantum channel in terms of its Kraus operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

The action of a quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$ on state given by a density operator $\rho$ is described by a completely positive trace preserving (CPTP) map:
$$
\rho \rightarrow \sum_k R_k \rho R_k^\dagger = \mathcal{E(\rho)} .
$$
The Kraus operators $R_k$ must obey the condition $\sum_kR_k^\dagger R_k = \mathcal{I}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity operator.

A fixed point $\rho_f$ of a channel is a state which is left unchanged by the action of the channel so that:
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho_f) = \rho_f 
$$
My question is: Given that we know the Kraus operators $R_k$ for a quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$, how can we find the fixed point(s) of that channel?

Is there a general process for obtaining an expression for $\rho_f$ in terms of $R_k$?

A related, maybe easier, question is whether we can prove that there exists a fixed point of a particular channel. Do all channels have fixed points?

Comment: Regarding your second question, the identity is always a fixed point of a trace preserving channel.

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: For your main question, there is a _fuerza bruta_ approach --- perhaps someone else will have a smarter idea. Expand $\rho$ in a basis and take inner products to extract the matrix element $\rho_{ij}$. Denoting $\langle i | R_{k} |l\rangle$ by $R_{kil}$, this leads to $\rho_{ij} = \sum_{lm}\rho_{lm}\sum_{k} R_{kil} R^{*}_{kjm}$. This is a linear system of equations for the basis coefficients $\rho_{ij}$ which in principle can be solved.

Comment: @anon1802 *"the identity is always a fixed point of a trace preserving channel."* -- This is incorrect, take e.g. the channel which maps every input to |0><0|.

Comment: General reading: https://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/MichaelWolf/QChannelLecture.pdf. Regarding your last question, yes, every channel has at least one positive semi-definite fixed point. (This is the quantum version of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem; see the linked notes.) For (numerically) finding fixed points, you can start by solving the corresponding eigenvalue equation for the eigenvector $\rho$. If the fixed point is unique, you get it immediately; otherwise, you have to massage the eigenvectors to get a positive semi-definite fixed point.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ah, sorry, you're right. The correct statement is that if $\mathcal{E}$ is trace-preserving then the identity is a fixed point of the adjoint map $\mathcal{E}^{*}$.

Comment: @anon1802 In fact, that's an if and only if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relevant result is given by Watrous in section 4.2.2 of [his book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/).
Here are two theorems proved in the section:

1. Let $\Phi\in\mathrm T(\mathcal X)$ be a *positive* and *trace-preserving* map, with $\mathcal X$ a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. Then there is some state $\rho$ such that $\Phi(\rho)=\rho$.
2. Let $\Phi$ be a *unital channel* (thus CPTP with $\Phi(I)=I$), and suppose its Kraus decomposition reads
   $$\Phi(X)=\sum_a A_a X A_a^\dagger.$$
   Then, for any linear operator $X$, we have $\Phi(X)=X$ *iff* $[X,A_a]=0$ for every $a$.